# On Animation Complete Free Space in Android TextView

Tags: java, android, animation, textview

I want to rescale android textView. But the problem is that when rescale animation completed. There is the problem of free space in View Area. How could i fix this issue..? Any one can guide me..?

**activity.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_white" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/windowTitleToolText1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="Title Text 1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="45dp" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/windowTitleToolText2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fillAfter="true"
                    android:fillEnabled="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                    android:text="Title Text 2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/windowTitleToolBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" >
            <ImageView ...... />
            <ImageView ...... />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**anim_scale_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="3000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        android:toXScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="0.5"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true" >
    </scale>

</set>
```

**Activity.java**

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.anim_scale_1);
a.reset();
a.setFillAfter(true);
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.windowTitleToolText1);
tv.clearAnimation();
tv.startAnimation(a);
```

[image: Free Space after Rescale animation complete]

Comment: Haven't tried but setting `LayoutParams (Height and Width to wrap_content)` after completion might do it.

Comment: @JibranKhan I have already set `wrap_content` for the Layout width and height